# Direct connection from IBM Cloudant to Tableau

Tags: ibm-cloud, tableau-api, cloudant, dashdb

i have a scenario where IBM Cloudant NoSQL DB is used. We're trying to see if there is a way to connect the data directly from Cloudant straight to Tableau to produce some dashboards, but i haven't found success with hooking it up directly. There is a service called IBM dashDB which i have trialed which allows data from Cloudant to flow into this service on the bluemix platform, and from there i can do a live extract of the data to Tableau.

Just wondering, has anyone successfully implemented a direct connection from Cloudant to Tableau without having to use dashDB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Tableau introduced support for JSON files in their 10.1 beta in the second half of 2016: https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/8/tableau-101-beta-here-58447

You might be able to export your data from Cloudant and use that new JSON file load feature to pull the data in. It's not the direct solution you are looking for but I figured it might be worth mentioning.

According to a comment in their community (https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1276 ) JSON support will be incremental:

> Our first step will be single files; then our plans are to allow for multiple files and then web services.